# Nested BulletSpan in Android

Tags: android, textview, bullet-span

How to create a nested `BulletSpan` for a `TextView`, well something like :

- item 1 has:

  - a
  - b
- item 2 has:

  - c
  - d

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML for this.

`&#8226;` will be your "Bullet" in HTML.

`textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("&#8226; item 1 has:<br/> &#8226; a<br/> &#8226; b <br/>");`

Comment: and the text padding? if you have a multiple line "Bullet" content ?

Comment: use spaces, as per [this post](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com/2011/04/html-in-textviews.html) Android html does not support something like "tab".